# Map result of 2 groupings to 2-dimensional object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model that I'd like to group on 2 columns:

```
ModelName.group(:location_id, :referrer).count
```

The result of this is an object that is difficult to deal with:

```
{
    [ '1', 'friend' ] => 100,
    [ '1', 'family' ] => 23,
    [ '2', 'friend' ] => 43,
    [ '2', 'family' ] => 65
}
```

I'd like to map these values to an easier to sue structure but I can't get it working.  Ideally it'd be something like:

```
{
    '1' => {
        'friend' => 100
        'family' => 23
    },
    '2' => {
        'friend' => 100
        'family' => 23
    }
}
```

How can I accomplish this (preferably it would work with a 3rd dimension as well)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take your current output and group it by every hash key, and then transform the hash values:

```
data.group_by { |key, _| key.first }
    .transform_values do |values|
      values.each_with_object({}) do |(keys, value), hash|
        hash[keys.last] = value
      end
    end
# {"1"=>{"friend"=>100, "family"=>23}, "2"=>{"friend"=>43, "family"=>65}}
```

Comment: Amazing.  I'm gonna do my best to follow this logic because this is some impressive data manipulation

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
original = {
  [ '1', 'friend' ] => 100,
  [ '1', 'family' ] => 23,
  [ '2', 'friend' ] => 43,
  [ '2', 'family' ] => 65
}
```

You can get there nicely by combining an autovivifying hash:

```
desired = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = { } }
```

and some nested destructing:

```
original.each_with_object(desired) do |((loc, ref), n), h|
  h[loc][ref] = n
end
desired
# {"1"=>{"friend"=>100, "family"=>23}, "2"=>{"friend"=>43, "family"=>65}}
```

Or, if you don't like predeclaring `desired`:

```
desired = original.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = { } }) do |((loc, ref), n), h|
  h[loc][ref] = n
end
# {"1"=>{"friend"=>100, "family"=>23}, "2"=>{"friend"=>43, "family"=>65}}
```

or perhaps:

```
reorg   = ->(((loc, ref), n), h) { h[loc][ref] = n }
desired = original.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = { } }, &reorg)
# {"1"=>{"friend"=>100, "family"=>23}, "2"=>{"friend"=>43, "family"=>65}}
```